# error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated

Tags: c++, object, compiler-errors, project, compiler-warnings

I have below class

```
class Cdata12Mnt
{
public:
    char IOBname[ID1_IOB_PIOTSUP-ID1_IOB_TOP][BOADNAM_MAX + 4];
    char ExIOBname[ID1_MAX_INF-ID1_EXIOB_U1TOP][BOADNAM_MAX + 4];
    char cflpath[256];
    char basetext[256];
    UINT database[ID1_MAX_INF];
    int State;

public:
    char SelectPath[256];

public:
    int GetIOBName(int slt,char *Name);
    Cdata12Mnt(char *SelectPath);
    virtual ~Cdata12Mnt();
    int     GetValue(int id);
    int     GetState() { return State; }
};
```

And I have function as below

```
Cdata12Mnt::Cdata12Mnt(char *SelectPath)
{
    SCTReg  reg;
    char    buf[256], *cpnt, *npnt, *bpnt1, *bpnt2;
    char    *startcode[] = {"CNTL_CODE ","SEGMENT "};
    char    *stopcode    = {"END_CNTL_CODE "};
    FILE    *fp;
    int     ii, infl;

    State = 0;

    for (ii = 0; ii < (ID1_IOB_PIOTSUP - ID1_IOB_TOP); ii++) {
        strcpy(IOBname[ii], "");
    }

    for (ii = 0; ii < (ID1_MAX_INF-ID1_EXIOB_U1TOP); ii++) {
        **strcpy(ExIOBname[ii], "");**
    }

    sprintf(cflpath, "%s\\%s", SelectPath, CDATAFL);

    if ((fp = fopen(cflpath,"r"))!=NULL) {
        for (ii = 0, infl = 0; fgets(buf, 256, fp) != NULL;) {
            if (infl == 0 && strncmp(buf, startcode[0], strlen(startcode[0])) == 0) {
                if ((cpnt = strchr(&buf[strlen(startcode[0])],*startcode[1])) != NULL) {
                    if (strncmp(cpnt,startcode[1], strlen(startcode[1])) == 0) {
                        infl = 1;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (infl == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            if (strncmp(buf,stopcode,strlen(stopcode))==0) {
                if (ii == ID1_EXIOB_U1TOP) {
                    for (int nDataNumber = ii; nDataNumber < ID1_MAX_INF; nDataNumber++) {
                        database[nDataNumber] = 0;
                    }
                }

                infl = 0;
                continue;
            }

            if (strncmp(&buf[14], " DD ", 4) == 0) {
                if ((cpnt=strchr(buf, ';')) != NULL) {
                    *cpnt = '\0';
                }

                if (ii >= ID1_IOB_TOP && ii < ID1_IOB_PIOTSUP) {
                    if ((bpnt1 = strchr(cpnt + 1,'(')) != NULL && (bpnt2=strchr(cpnt + 1,')'))!=NULL && bpnt1 < bpnt2) {
                        *bpnt2 = '\0';
                        *(bpnt1 + BOADNAM_MAX + 1) = '\0';
                        strcpy(IOBname[ii-ID1_IOB_TOP], bpnt1 + 1);
                    }
                }

                if (ii >= ID1_EXIOB_U1TOP && ii < ID1_MAX_INF) {
                    if ((bpnt1 = strchr(cpnt + 1, '(')) != NULL && (bpnt2=strchr(cpnt+1,')'))!=NULL && bpnt1 < bpnt2) {
                            *bpnt2='\0';
                            *(bpnt1+BOADNAM_MAX+1)='\0';
                            strcpy(ExIOBname[ii-ID1_EXIOB_U1TOP], bpnt1 + 1);
                    }
                }

                for (cpnt = &buf[18]; cpnt != NULL;) {
                    if ((npnt=strchr(cpnt, ',')) != NULL)
                        *npnt='\0';
                }

                if (strchr(cpnt,'H')!=NULL) {
                    sscanf(cpnt,"%XH",&database[ii]);
                } else {
                    database[ii]=atoi(cpnt);
                }

                ii++;
                cpnt = npnt;

                if (cpnt != NULL) {
                    cpnt++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
} else {
    State=-1;
}
```

When I compile this function in Visual studio 2008, it gives me error at `strcpy(IOBname[ii],"");` as below

> error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated

How to fix this error?

Comment: Your project settings contains a flag that tells the compiler to treat warnings as errors. Turn that flag off and you will only have the original warning (whatever that is).

Comment: And by the way, why do you have old C-style string in a C++ project? Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), it will work out much better in the long run. Also, instead of old C-style arrays, use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)).

Comment: Fix your warnings and it will build

Answer (score 42):

The error says that a warning was treated as an error, therefore your problem is a warning message!  The object file is then not created **because** there was an error.  So you need to check your warnings and fix them.

In case you don't know how to find them: Open the `Error List` (`View` > `Error List`) and click on `Warning`.

Comment: Any solution which is not purely VisualStudio? I am having this same issue under another IDE.

Answer (score 39):

Go to `project properties -> configurations properties -> C/C++ -> treats warning as error -> No (/WX-)`.

Comment: So your solution is : "blindly ignore all warnings" ?

Comment: @mojtaba setoodeh, ignoring warnings is not a fix, but a bypass.

Comment: Not a valid solution!

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. If you are working on a shared code base and the modules causing this error aren't of concern to you, this solution should get you going so that you can focus on what you are doing.

Comment: Why do you care in development mode. just disable as suggested and focus on work. Later enable it again, fix the warnings before checking in.

Comment: Not valid answer

Comment: It also fails on warnings like C4101, unreferenced local variable. Everyone may have a different opinion about that, but I don't like that at all, especially during development phase.

Comment: "blindly ignore all warnings" is a good solution especially when one need to deal with a legacy projects

Comment: Compiling legacy & 3rd party code may necessitate ignoring warnings in some way.  Ideally disable them by specific warning number. One of the answers shows how with pragmas; warnings can also be disabled in Visual Studio via `Properties > C/C++ > Advanced > Disable Specific Warnings`.

Comment: I'm actually fine with the approach to this answer, at least for certain situations. However in my case, it's already set to "no." -1.

Answer (score 9):

As a side-note, you can enable/disable individual warnings using `#pragma`. You can have a look at the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx)

**From the documentation:**

```
// pragma_warning.cpp
// compile with: /W1
#pragma warning(disable:4700)
void Test() {
   int x;
   int y = x;   // no C4700 here
   #pragma warning(default:4700)   // C4700 enabled after Test ends
}

int main() {
   int x;
   int y = x;   // C4700
}
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that you want to disable the `warning`, not `2220`.

Answer (score 8):

This error message is very confusing. I just fixed the other 'warnings' in my project and I really had only one (simple one):

> warning C4101: 'i': unreferenced local variable

After I commented this unused `i`, and compiled it, the other error went away.

Comment: I confirm that, i had a similar issue today. Had an "Unreachable code" warning somewhere plus this confusing "no 'object file generated'". Fixing the unreachable warning also eliminated the second one. Kind of strange.

Answer (score 2):

This warning is about unsafe use of strcpy. Try `IOBname[ii]='\0';` instead.